# How to get rid of __webpack_exports__ in output

Tags: webpack

How can I get rid of this line that is in webpack's output?

```js
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
```

I couldn't find any info in the docs about what `__webpack_exports__` is or how to omit it from the output. Any pointers?

Some context:
My simple project using webpack has 1 entry point and 1 module the entry point depends on (see below for code). My intention is use webpack's output in the one and only `<script>` tag in an html file. And I'd like the output to be as close as possible to if I were to combine the javascript by hand.

### Input files

#### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: { main: "./src/app.ts", },
  output: {
    iife: false,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: "script.js",
  },
  optimization: { minimize: false, },
  resolve: { extensions: [".ts", ".js"], },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
    ]
  }
};
```

#### app.ts

```ts
import { name } from "./variable";
console.log(name);
export let foo = "baz";
```

#### variable.ts

```ts
export const name = 'gary';
// export const name: null = 'gary';
let foo = "foo";
```

### Output file

#### script.js

```js
/******/ "use strict";
var __webpack_exports__ = {};

// UNUSED EXPORTS: foo

;// CONCATENATED MODULE: ./src/variable.ts
const variable_name = 'gary';
// export const name: null = 'gary';
let foo = "foo";

;// CONCATENATED MODULE: ./src/app.ts

console.log(variable_name);
let app_foo = "baz";
```